# How to find number of a specific integer in an array of Fixnums ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, integer, normalization

I'm doing an exercise now where I'm looking for all of the zeros in an array.

The input is:

`numbers = [1, 3, 500, 200, 4000, 3000, 10000, 90, 20, 500000]`

I want to sort them into a hash by the number of zeros. The expected output is:

`expected = {0=>[1, 3], 2=>[500, 200], 3=>[4000, 3000], 4=>[10000], 1=>[90, 20], 5=>[500000]}`

I have the structure built but I'm not sure how to count the number of zeros:

```
grouped = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = []}
numbers.each do |num|
  grouped[num] << num
end
```

**EDITED for clarity:**
Any advice would be appreciated. Also, a lot of the advice I read on this recommended converting the array of integers to  a string in order to solve the problem. Is there a way to count the number of digits (not just zeros) without converting the array to a string? The expected output in this case would look like:

`expected = {1=>[1, 3], 2=>[90, 20], 3=>[500, 200], 4=>[4000, 3000], 5=>[10000], 6=>[500000]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If an element of the hash you wish to construct is `n => array`, where `n` is a non-negative integer, is `array` to contain all elements of `numbers` that have `n` zero digits.? If so, you should change "I want to sort them into a hash by the number of digits" to "...the number of zero digits".  Also, you should show the desired output for the input `numbers`.

Comment: You switch between "count number of digits" and "count number of zeroes" in the question, and your examples are all single leading digit and following zeroes. Could you please make it clearer what you need the output to be with your input example (just build it by hand and add to end of question)?

Comment: Plus one for calling me out on my lack of clarity. Sorry about that. It was number of zeroes I was looking for.

Comment: Joe, I suggest you edit your question to incorporate the clarification that is in your comment.  Many others may read your question and the answers in future, so you owe it to them to be as clear as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to group non-negative integers by the number of zero digits they contain, you can do this:

```
def nbr_zeroes(n)
  return 1 if n == 0
  m = n
  i = 0
  while m > 0
    i += 1 if m % 10 == 0
    m /= 10
  end
  i
end

numbers = [1, 3, 500, 200, 4000, 3000, 10000, 90, 20, 500000]
numbers.group_by { |i| nbr_zeroes(i) }
  #=> { 0=>[1, 3], 2=>[500, 200], 3=>[4000, 3000], 4=>[10000] }

numbers = [100000, 100001, 304070, 3500040, 314073, 2000, 314873, 0]
numbers.group_by { |i| nbr_zeroes(i) }
  #=> { 5=>[100000],    4=>[100001, 3500040], 3=>[304070, 2000],
  #     1=>[314073, 0], 0=>[314873] }
```

Answer (score 1):

Like many transformations you'll want to do, this one's found in [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html).

Grouping by number of digits:

```
grouped = numbers.group_by { |n| Math.log10(n).to_i + 1 }
# => {1=>[1, 3], 3=>[500, 200], 4=>[4000, 3000], 5=>[10000], 2=>[90, 20], 6=>[500000]}
```

Grouping by number of zeroes:

```
grouped = numbers.group_by { |n| n.to_s.match(/0+$/) ? $&.length : 0 }
# => {0=>[1, 3], 2=>[500, 200], 3=>[4000, 3000], 4=>[10000], 1=>[90, 20], 5=>[500000]}
```

The `group_by` method is a handy way to convert an Array to a Hash with things organized into pigeon-holes.

Comment: Remove the +1 to count the zeros.

Comment: @MarkThomas Ah, I misread the question and did the "number of digits" instead.

Comment: `n.to_s.count( '0' )` also works in the group_by block for the second example, and is a little quicker.

Comment: @NeilSlater That's a much better approach. Good call.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up using

```
grouped = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = []}
numbers.each do |num|
  grouped[num.to_s.count('0')] << num
end
```

but I really liked the variation in responses. I didn't realize there were so many ways to go about this. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Looks good, Joe. +1. A couple of options (not necessarily improvements): 1. you could incorporate the first line in the second by changing the latter to `numbers.each_with_object(Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = []}) do |num, grouped|`. or 2. change the third line to `(grouped[num.to_s.count('0')] ||= []) << num` (and optionally change the second line to `numbers.each_with_object({}) do |num, grouped|`.  I vote for this as the best answer.  Feel free to change the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

Group by floor of log base 10?

```
1.9.3-p484 :014 > numbers.each {|n| grouped[Math.log10(n).floor] << n}
 => [1, 3, 500, 200, 4000, 3000, 10000, 90, 20, 500000] 
1.9.3-p484 :016 > grouped   
 => {0=>[1, 3], 2=>[500, 200], 3=>[4000, 3000], 4=>[10000], 1=>[90, 20], 5=>[500000]}
```

Or try `1 + Math.log10(n).floor` if you need the keys to be the actual number of digits.